# How can I create a sequence of functions and loop them in Swift?

Tags: ios, loops, swift

I am trying to build a feature so that when you shake the iPhone, the particles on the screen will fly around.

I have hooks to tie into when the shaking begins and ends.

I will create a UIPushBehavior and add it to the animator scene when shaking begins and when it ends I will remove the UIPushBehavior from the animator.

But to get a good shaking experience I want to vary the push angle while the device is in motion.

How can I recreate this pseudo code in Swift?

```
override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake)
    {
        self.push = UIPushBehavior()
        self.push!.angle = -self.angle!
        self.animator.addBehavior(self.push)
        // BEGIN Pseudo Code
        self.sequence = Sequence({self.push.angle = self.angle!}, {self.push.angle = -self.angle}, 
        delay: 100ms)
       // END Pseudo Code
    }
}

override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
{
    if (motion == UIEventSubtype.MotionShake)
    {

       self.animator.removeBehavior(self.push)
       // BEGIN Pseudo Code
       self.sequence.stopSequence()
       // END Pseudo Code
    }
}
```

So as you can see I want to be able to define 2 functions (which change the direction of push angle by 180 degrees) to be looped every 100ms, until I call stopSequence()

How can I actually do this with Swift?

Comment: You are looking for a definition of the `Sequence` class?

Comment: There is no Sequence class in swift. That is example code of what I am trying to do with a made up Class API. Is there anything in Swift to achieve the nature of what the Pseudo code is trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
class MySequence {
  var functions : Array<() -> ()>

  func runSequenceOneTime () -> Void {
    for function in functions {
      function ()
    }
  }

  func stopSequence () -> Void {
    // uninstall alarm
  }

  func startSequence (delay: Double) -> Void {
    // install alarm w/ runSequenceOneTime
  }

  init (delay: Double, _ functions: (() -> ())...) {
    self.functions = functions
    self.startSequence (delay)
  }
}
```

and then you'd create an instance of `MySequence` as:

```
var mySeq = MySequence (delay: 0.1, func1, func2, func3)
```

Comment: hmm your class looks like it takes a start function, and a repeat function. I am looking for something that accepts any number of functions in a certain order and loops them continuously with a certain delay setting between each entire sequence loop. So for example you would define func1, func2, func3, and delay 0ms. This would run func1, then func2, then func3, then back to func1, func2, func3, and it would loop over and over until you stopped the sequence.

Comment: In the code 'init (delay: Double, _ functions: (() -> ())...) {' what is the _ in front of functions:

Comment: It means that the argument does not have an 'external name'; that is, you don't need to provide the `functions:` keyword.